# CSS filter background images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a filter over the background image of the div in the code below as done on the homepage of http://www.theverge.com/. Honestly I have no idea how how to get around it.
This is what I have:

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="box"></div>
</a>

<style>
    #box{
        background-image: url("http://goo.gl/pdyi7R");
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    #box:hover {
        background-color: red;
        opacity: 5;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Just FYI: `div` inside `a` is invalid.

Comment: @putvande in html5 it valid to have `div`s in anchors - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element (and you call yourself a developer in html5!)

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter element in your box with the filter color

```
<a href="#">

    <div id="box"><div id="filter"></div></div>

    </a>


    <style>


#box{
    background-image: url("http://goo.gl/pdyi7R");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#filter {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
    opacity:0.4;
}

</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9n3ge6r1/

Answer (score 0):

The div is invalid, since it's a starting tag. Unless you want a navigation bar on top of the div.

For the background of the website it would look like this for the div tag.

```
 <div class="box" style="background-image:url("");">
   <a href="#"></a>
 </div>
```

Using the background image on the div only, makes it easier for editing.
Now you can use a filter to change the style of the image.

W3 Schools has the list of filter options and styles.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp